# How to use Regex in a Calculated Column's formula for finding a string pattern in another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to generate an ID on emails that come on my site. Essentially, when the email subject matches the regex, it generates an ID based on that pattern. My question is how do I use regex on SP's calculated column formula?

I've seen this online but it doesn't show any regex at all:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/519981/sharepoint-column-validation-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SharePoint calculated column formulas does not support using RegEx in the formulas.

You can only use the predefined supported functions in the SharePoint calculated column formulas.

You can find the list of all supported functions in the SharePoint calculated column formulas at: [Examples of common formulas in SharePoint lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)